# Unreadable Notebook ... FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, conda

I am experiencing this error every time I attempt to open a Jupyter notebook. Around 1:30pm, I did two things on my new Mac mini with the M1 chip:

1. `conda update --all`
2. downloaded ChromeDriver for Selenium web scraping

Since then I cannot open any of my Jupyter notebooks. I am able to start Jupyter notebook on my Safari browser from the terminal but not open any notebooks or a new Python3 notebook. I also created a new environment with conda installed and still received the same error.

Comment: What was the complete error message that you got? Was there any additional output on the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Found a "solution:" revert back to initial installation of conda using *conda install --revision 1*, and I am now able to open Jupyter notebooks.

Question remains whether *conda update --all* or *conda update* is problematic on the new m1 chip. Feel free to post your thoughts. Thanks!